# Coldfusion querying database update field with todays date

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to query the database and have it find the correct id and update the id at the correct number it is assigned to and then have it find the Date_Complete field and have it update with todays date.

```
<cfquery name="completeBatch">
    UPDATE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work (Date_Complete)
    SET    Date_Complete = getDate()
    WHERE  id = 5
</cfquery>
```

I thought this would update the Date_Complete field where id equals the 5th id (which increments by 1 as there submitted into the database). And that it would set the Date_Complete to todays date. All I am getting is a blank screen with nothing happening to the database.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I am trying to get to work to create my function for it to work properly.

```
<cfcomponent>


<cffunction name="updateRecord" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true">
     <cfset var completeBatch = ''> 
    <cfquery name="completeBatch">
        UPDATE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work (Date_Complete)
        SET    Date_Complete = getDate()
        WHERE  ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What's the reason for having `(Date_Complete)` in your query? You should turn on debugging and add an abort after the query runs to see what is being done.

Comment: It's not necessary to put it there, that's why it's in your `SET` statement

Comment: Correct, those are related. You can name the argument anything you want as long as you reference it with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the `(Date_Complete)` in your `UPDATE`

```
<cfquery name="completeBatch">
  UPDATE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work
  SET    Date_Complete = getDate()
  WHERE  ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
```